# Not able to load data into hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, bigdata

While loading data into Hive tables, i'm Getting following error:

```
"Loading data to table test.temp1
Moved: 'hdfs://mdckd.kk.hyy.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/temp1/000000_0' to trash at: hdfs://mdckd.kk.hyy.com:8020/user/lams/.Trash/Current
Table test.temp1 stats: [numFiles=1014, numRows=0, totalSize=50113, rawDataSize=0]"
```

Looks like my data is going to trash but i don't understand why. Please help. Following is my table definition and the query i am using:

```
      CREATE TABLE `temp1`(
      `col1` int,
      `col2` int,
      `col3` int,
      `col4` int,
      `col5` int,
      `col6` int,
      `col7` int,
      `col8` int,
      `col9` int,
      `col10` int)
      ROW FORMAT SERDE
       'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
       STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
       'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT
       'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
       LOCATION
       'hdfs://mdckd.kk.hyy.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/temp1'
       TBLPROPERTIES (
       'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true',
       'numFiles'='548',
       'numRows'='547',
       'rawDataSize'='131280',
       'totalSize'='483505',
       'transient_lastDdlTime'='1490261019')

    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE temp1 
    select * from
     (
       select * from tab1
       union all
       select * from tab2
       union all
       select * from tab3
       union all
       select * from tab4
       union all
       select * from tab5  
    )p;
```

Comment: Create table looks strange. there is no need in that `TBLPROPERTIES  ` sentence when creating table

Answer (score 0):

The data that is already in your table is going to trash, because this exactly what `OVERWRITE` means.
If you want to append and not truncate, use `INSERT INTO TABLE` (or `INSERT INTO` in newer versions).

P.s.

You don't need the outer query.

```
insert into table temp1

            select * from tab1
union all   select * from tab2
union all   select * from tab3
union all   select * from tab4
union all   select * from tab5  
;
```